# NodeJS - SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, instance

I've created an ubuntu instance on my university server. I've installed NodeJS and NPM and can send files with a FTP connection.

I sent following NodeJS webserver file to my intance and want to run it on the instance ip-adress.

```
var http = require(“http“);
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {‚content-type’: ‚text/plain‚});
    response.write(‘Hello World’);
    response.end;
}).listen(3000‚141.28.107.7);
console.log(“server is running“);
```

When I run this file with

```
sudo nodejs server.js
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host nodejs
/home/robin/files/webserver.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { var http = require(“http“);
                                                                                 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:148:18)
    at node.js:405:3
```

Where's my error in reasoning?
Thanks!

Comment: Wild guess hostname between quotes `.listen(3000‚ "141.28.107.7");`

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be using weird quotes : `“`. Use standard double quotes `"` or single quotes `'`.

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    response.write('Hello World');
    response.end();
}).listen(3000‚'141.28.107.7');
console.log('server is running');
```